# How can i upgrade this regex not capture "1hey" or "123_456_bye" or "1123_hey"

Tags: java, regex

I'm regex to extract number meeting the following example, in bold is what needs to be caught:

**0**:**0** he9lo **12.33** hello **00** 3a>**4** hello7 **5**<=**6** 8hello **-45,6** 10help 123_456_bye **1**=a2 1123_hey

The goal/conditions is to "extract" sequences of numbers that do not contain any character but can contain symbols in the like . or , or : to catch decimals(, or .) or time(:).

Tried to add [^a-zA-Z] in many places because my main issue is to avoid capturing sequeces with numbers+words.
I also tried to use the [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) without many results (need more practice.)
Working in [in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1UbPRu/7) to experiment the regex since I find much easier with the tools and references they provide.

Here is the regex i'm using so far which is still capturing("wrongly") the following examples: 10help 123_456_bye 1123_hey

```regex
(?:^|<|>|=|<=|>=|\:|\s)([-]?[0-9]{1,}((\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?)
```

Comment: Try `(?<!\w)-?[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great answer thanks! And if I also want to ignore other symbols between numbers like __1*1__ or __2-2__ ?

Comment: Maybe `(?<!\S)-?[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?(?!\S)`. What do you need in fact?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are some specific symbols that I do not want to ignore the numbers like = > < <= >= : but others like - _ I do. The previous solution ignores all symbols to it does not work with the  5<=6. Thanks for the fast reply again! (I cannot upvote bcs I do not have 15 rep : (

Answer (score 2):

You may consider matching a number when it is not preceded with a word char and not followed with a word char.

The problem is that you cannot use a word boundary at the start of the pattern due to the optional `-`, `-?`. The `\b-?` pattern will fail the match in case the hyphen is present in the string before the number and if it is preceded with a non-word char.

You also need to allow matching before and after some special chars, `=`, `>`, `<`, `:` and whitespace

You may use

```
(?<!\w)(?<=[\s=><:]|^)-?[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?(?!\w)(?=[\s=><:]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PfaIvm/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\w)` - no word char immediately before is allowed
- `(?<=[\s=><:]|^)` - immediately before, there must be a whitespace, `=`, `>`, `<`, `:` or start of string
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?`  - an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then 1 or 2 digits
- `(?!\w)` - no word char immediately after is allowed
- `(?=[\s=><:]|$)` - immediately after, there must be a whitespace, `=`, `>`, `<`, `:` or end of string.